# Insertar registros aumentando el valor del campo. (Ms SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, select, insert

Se tiene la siguiente tabla `personas`:

[image]

Necesito insertar un nuevo registro y para agilizar necesito seguir desde el último folio existente.

Hago esto en **Microsoft SQL Server:**

```sql
INSERT INTO personas VALUES ((SELECT MAX (registro) FROM personas)+1),'ALAN BRITO','HOMBRE','40')
```

Y me devuelve el siguiente error:

```
'Subqueries are not allowed in this context. Only scalar expressions are allowed.'
```

**¿Qué estoy haciendo mal? ¿Cómo lo soluciono?**

Nota:

- Ya cuento con un gran número de personas. El registro debe ir por alrededor de **345.992 personas** registradas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes un problema simple de sintaxis, en este caso te sobra `VAUES`, inserta el `SELECT` directamente:

```
INSERT INTO personas (registro, sexo, nombre, edad) 
SELECT MAX (registro) + 1, 'ALAN BRITO', 'HOMBRE','40'
FROM personas
```

En otro orden de cosas, tienes disponible la característica identidad (identity) que convierte un campo en autonumérico, eso hace el trabajo por ti, incrementando automáticamente el registro, sin necesidad de que tu lo especifiques.

Comment: Fantástico Roger, he realizado la corrección y no he vuelto a tener el error.

Gracias por el consejo y como organizar mis querys.

Comment: @EjayMaldonaldo recuerda si es la repuesta, marcalo con el check